# word page number in header table

Tags: visual-foxpro, word-automation

I have a table in header with 1 row, column 1 is a image and column 2 some text.

I want to add page number to the third cell with *vertical alignment bottom*.

I tried but do not know which object to add the `.PageNumber.Add( )`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do it to the .Cells(1,3) of the table. You might need .Range() on the end of that.

Tamar

Comment: I tried oTable.cell(1,3).range.pagenumber.add and it returns error "member pagenumber does not evaluate to an object ", I have tried cells, pagenumbers and similar error occurs.

Comment: It's a long time since I looked at this stuff. Now that I do, it's clear that .PageNumbers.Add is for putting a page number right into a header or footer, not into an object that's on the header or footer. Doing what you want via a macro (in Word 2010) results in this code:


Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\Tamar\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\14\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("Plain Number").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
        RichText:=True

Comment: I finally use field.add(oRange,wdFieldPage) to do it, since I have never tried using templates and cannot be sure if the absolute path will have any impact if the application is run on other machine.

Comment: just that I forget to add "oRange.end = oRange.End - 1" required in the table cell so I was stuck for two days.

Answer (score -1):

just for helping others, after the last comment of using "oRange.end = oRange.End - 1" which was the answer I was looking:

I was trying to make a footer that has a hyperlink to the start of my document, and the page number.
When exporting this to .pdf, the link is clickable and takes you to the table of contents.

my code is:

```
foreach (Section wordSection in doc.Sections)
{
    Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    footerRange.Font.Size = 12;
    Table ftable = doc.Tables.Add(footerRange, 1, 2);
    ftable.PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
    ftable.PreferredWidth = 100;
    doc.Hyperlinks.Add(ftable.Cell(1, 1).Range, Address: "", SubAddress: "_top", ScreenTip: "", TextToDisplay: "Contents");
    Range t2r = ftable.Cell(1, 2).Range;
    t2r.End = t2r.End - 1;
    doc.Fields.Add(t2r, Type: WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
    ftable.Cell(1, 2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;                   
}
```

thank you user3876120